# Slow down rendering graphics in java

Tags: java, graphics, render

When I run the code below  the beginning position of x and y and the final position of x and y render. I want each position of x and y to render as the tick method runs and changes the x and y values by the speed. Basically I want to be able to control the speed of an object as it moves.

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
           g.drawImage(JamesTexture.james, x, y, width, height, null);
    }

    public void tick() {

        if (run) {
            if (!stop) {

                    int z = Maze.fx.size() - 1;
                    int i = 1;// speed
                    xx = getPathX(z);
                    yy = getPathY(z);

                    while (z > 0) {

                        if (xx > (getPathX(z - 1))) {
                            xx = xx - i;
                            x = xx;
                            if (xx < (getPathX(z - 1))) {
                                xx = (getPathX(z - 1));
                            }
                        } else if (xx < (getPathX(z - 1))) {
                            xx = xx + i;
                            x = xx;
                            if (xx > (getPathX(z - 1))) {
                                xx = (getPathX(z - 1));
                            }
                        } else if (yy > (getPathY(z - 1))) {
                            yy = yy - i;
                            y = yy;
                            if (yy < (getPathY(z - 1))) {
                                yy = (getPathY(z - 1));
                            }
                        } else if (yy < (getPathY(z - 1))) {
                            yy = yy + i;
                            y = yy;
                            if (yy < (getPathY(z - 1))) {
                                yy = (getPathY(z - 1));
                            }
                        } else {

                            z--;
                            stop = true;                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int getPathX(int z) {
        List<Integer> fx = Maze.fx;
        z = fx.get(z);
        return z * 32;
    }

    int getPathY(int z) {
        List<Integer> fy = Maze.fy;
        z = fy.get(z);
        return z * 32;
    }
```

Comment: You need to use a Timer, so that each time the Timer fires you re-draw the scene based on the new positions.

Comment: Does this GUI use Swing, AWT, ..crayons to make the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion as I cannot comment yet, but it might be that your while loop finishes the entire maze in one call. I think we'd need more of your code to be sure, but try to add a `break` statement at the end of **each** if statement in your while loop like so:

```
if (xx > (getPathX(z - 1))) {
    xx = xx - i;
    x = xx;
    if (xx < (getPathX(z - 1))) {
        xx = (getPathX(z - 1));
    }

    break;
}
```

Check if that fixes it. It is of course dependant on the speed the *tick()* function is called with.

Comment: The call the to get functions traverse an array by passing an int that represents the appropriate index. if i print the x and y values within the while loop the x and y values do get affected. however if i print the x and y values in the render method I only get the beginning x and y values and the final x and y values which is the end of the the maze.

Comment: Can you add that output to your question? Preferably so that it's visible which x and y come from the render method and which come from the tick method.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably over kill but the Thread class has a .sleep method which take nano seconds as parameters
 The thread(and therefore the program I think) would stop for given amount of time

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to handle this, because you can never exactly 'predict' how much time will be spent until the image that you are rendering is actually displayed. What you can do is measure the time(s) that elapsed between the previous tick(s) and the current tick.

```
delta time = current tick time - last tick time
```

This gives you the *actual delta time* that elapsed. So how do you fetch the tick time? I believe in Java the Clock, System and Timer classes provide various functions that each come with different precision and granularity. Typically, some of these functions depend on the hardware clock, some might be interrupted by various software and hardware events, some experience problems when multiple hardware cores are context switching, some might occasionally even run backwards.. It's a zoo and you need to read the docs carefully to understand what you are actually measuring. Generally though, millisecond precision is decent enough for most applications. E.g. this gets you the time in seconds (as a double with plenty of precision for millisecond ranges).

```
double stime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The speed is generally expressed as distance per time unit such as

```
meters per second (m / s)
```

You can then compute the distance the object needs to move by multiplying the delta time that elapsed with the speed.

```
delta object movement = delta elapsed time * speed
```

If you want to slow down the movement of your objects, you reduce the speed.

If you have a very 'stable' system framerate (and if you use standard double buffering this is mostly the case), you might be ok with a delta between the last 2 ticks, but of course you can use different prediction schemes to try to anticipate slowdowns if you have huge bursts of processing at irregular intervals. Getting a predictable framerate is why making good games is still hard to do.